# Adding NSPopoverDelegate to my MainWindowController

Tags: monomac

I need to add a delegate to my `MainWindowController` - which has all the outlets and actions and drives the program. In `ObjectiveC`, the following would work

`NSWindowController < NSPopoverDelegate >`

How would I do this in `MonoMac`? Again, to put it a different way, I would like my `NSWindowController` to be the delegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way to do this in MonoMac is to nest a private class inside your MainWindowController that derives from NSPopoverDelegate. Because your delegate has to derive from the base delegate class, you can't really make your MainWindowController itself the delegate.

e.g.

```
public partial class MainWindowController : MonoMac.AppKit.NSWindowController
{
    public override void AwakeFromNib()
    {
        myPopover.Delegate = new MyPopoverDelegate();

        base.AwakeFromNib();
    }

    private class MyPopoverDelegate : NSPopoverDelegate
    {
        public override bool ShouldClose(NSPopover popover)
        {
            // etc...
        }
    }
```

If you *really* want your MainWindowController to function as the delegate, you can use the `WeakDelegate` property (which takes an object) and manually export the delegate methods. This is not the preferred pattern:

```
    public override void AwakeFromNib()
    {
        myPopover.WeakDelegate = this;

        base.AwakeFromNib();
    }

    [Export("popoverShouldClose:")]
    private bool PopoverShouldClose(NSPopover popover)
    {
        // etc...
    }
```

Comment: I'm having trouble finding NSPopover Anything.  The MonoMac dll's that I've found have and AppKit namespace, but no NSPopover or NSPopoverDelegate.  Do I need to build the monomac dll from source to get it?

Comment: It's in `MonoMac.AppKit`. You shouldn't need to build from source.

Comment: I was using the MonoDevelop that came with Unity3D, and the Mono framework that comes from the Mono site.  NSPopover was not in Monomac.AppKit for me, when running that way.  Using Xamarin Studio, I do get NSPopover in Monomac.AppKit.